# Principal value of the argument of z

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is the principal value of the argument of z always in the interval of -pi and pi?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. Sometimes the interval $[0,2\pi[$ is used. It is just convention.

Any half-open interval with length $2\pi$ would suffice, but $]-\pi,\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi[$ are the most popular one due to the intrinsic connections of argument to trigonometric functions.